# Физика автомобильного движения. ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

Доброй ночи. Скажите пожалуйста, где можно прочитать или найти пример движения автомобиля с физикой ближней к реальной, видом сверху. Не важно какой движок, но главное что-бы на ActionScript. На хабре была статья, но она не очень подходит.

Answer (score 1):

[раз](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/06/16/create-a-flash-racing-game-tutorial-as3-version/)
[два](http://www.freeactionscript.com/2010/06/as3-car-movement-acceleration-turning-braking/)

на русском не искал

примеры без-движковые, с нуля

Comment: Везде искал. И без движков тоже. Наверное придется писать самому.